Prevent SQL from matching trailing whitespaces and instead match condition explicitly
I have a SQL table of distinct addresses. Some of the addresses have a trailing white space. Some of the addresses with a trailing whitespace also has the original, without the whitespace.
This proves problematic in joins, as when I join the original address, both of the addresses (whitespace, and non whitespace) returns as a match.
How can I complete a join so that only the exact addressid is matched?
select a.addressline3, b.[id] addressid1 
from addresstable a 
left join pii_address b on a.AddressLine3 = b.address

returns:

where
select * 
from pii_address 
where address = ''

returns

''
' '
More explicitly:
select * 
from Parsed_ADP_json..pii_address 
where address = '1 FLETCHER HOUSE'


returns 1 FLETCHER HOUSE and 1 FLETCHER HOUSE , note extra whitespace at end.
Lastly, the results from both of these searches are the same:
select a.*, b.*  
from table1 a
left join pii_address b on a.AddressLine1 = b.address collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
where AddressLine1 = '1 FLETCHER HOUSE                '

and
select a.*, b.*  
from table1 a
left join pii_address b on a.AddressLine1 = b.address collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
where AddressLine1 = '1 FLETCHER HOUSE'

BUT they are different when there is leading whitespace:
select a.*, b.*  
from table1 a
left join pii_address b on a.AddressLine1 = b.address collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
where AddressLine1 = ' 1 FLETCHER HOUSE'


You can use LIKE  instead of = but then if any of the addresses contain wildcards this won't work as desired

@MartinSmith where AddressLine1 LIKE '1 FLETCHER HOUSE      ' ESCAPE CHAR(0) or some other escape character should work unless your data is really weird

SQL Server automatically ignores trailing white spaces. You can check this article on the same here
An alternate I could think of is checking data length (not the normal length) along with string equality.
Given example below:
SELECT a.addressline3
    ,b.[id] addressid1 
FROM addresstable a 
LEFT JOIN pii_address b 
    ON a.AddressLine3 = b.address
WHERE DATALENGTH(a.AddressLine3) = DATALENGTH(b.address)

You can include this length condition at your convenience.
edit: using multiple joining conditions
SELECT a.addressline3
    ,b.[id] addressid1 
FROM addresstable a 
LEFT JOIN pii_address b 
    ON a.AddressLine3 = b.address
    AND DATALENGTH(a.AddressLine3) = DATALENGTH(b.address)


use AND instead of WHERE and it works. Joining under both conditions works

@Sam Please try not "beg" for votes here in this way
